# PHP query for copying tables

Tags: php, html, mysql, copying

This has to be somewhere online but I am having no luck after hours of trying to do this.

So I've HTML form on one page and a PHP page that creates a database fine..

```
<form action="createdb.php" method="post">
<label for="dbname"><b>Name of DB</b></label>    
<input type="text" name="dbname" id="dbname"/>
<input type="submit" value="Create DB">
```

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysqli_error());
$dbname = $_POST['dbname'];
if (mysqli_query($conn,"CREATE DATABASE $dbname")) {
    echo "Database created";    
} else {
   echo "Database was not created"; 
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Then I have underneath the PHP code these forms.. The form for creating the tables work fine within the DB that has just been created.. But its the form for copying tables from a DB already created into the newly created DB.

```
<form action="createtable.php" method="post">
<label for="tablename"><b>Create Table within new DB</b></label>    
<input type="text" name="tablename" id="tablename"/>
<input type="hidden" name="holdname" value="<?php echo $dbname ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Create Table">
</form>
<p>OR</p>
<form action="copytables.php" method="post">
<label for="tablename"><b>Copy RSS Tables</b></label>    
<input type="text" name="tablename" id="tablename" readonly/>
<input type="hidden" name="holdname" value="<?php echo $dbname ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Copy Tables">
</form>
```

I wanted to copy the tables, structure and data called 'lookup_age' and 'score' into the new DB from a database called 'rss_db'. I've rewrote the PHP page needed in many different ways and ATM it has been left like this, as of something I seen on W3schools, which confused me even more. I know it can be easily done via PHPMYADMIN but need it through a query now and HTML form if possible. Heres what I have as followed but wondering what should the query line actually be if possible..

```
 <?php
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysqli_error());
 $dbname =$_POST['holdname']; 
 mysqli_select_db($conn,"$dbname");
 mysqli_select_db($conn,"rss_db");

 $sql = "
 INSERT lookup_age
 INTO $dbname
 FROM rss_db";

 mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if these will help but you could try:

```
create table `table2` like `table1`; 
insert `table2` select * from `table`;

or, as a single line perhaps

create table `table2` as select * from `table1`;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query, to copy the tables:

```
$sql = " create table  '$dbname' as select * FROM 'rss_db'";
```

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY FOUND IT!! As simple as...

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $dbname.lookup_age   
SELECT * FROM rss_db.lookup_age";
```